# Yii2 QueryBuilder andFilterCompare with SubQuery result

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have a query in Yii2 as follows:

```
$Query = (new Query())
->select([
    'i.id as order_id',
    'i.uid as order_uid',
    'i.status as order_status',
    'i.created as order_created',
    'i.car_id as car_id',
    'i.user_id as user_id',
    'cc.customer_id as customer_id',
    'cc.make_id as make_id',
    'cc.model_id as model_id',
    'cc.color_id as color_id',
    'cc.plate_country as plate_country',
    'cc.plate_text as plate_text',
    'mk.title as make_title',
    'md.title as model_title',
    'c.title as customer_title',
    '(select coalesce(sum(cost),0) from moneyflow where order_uid = i.uid and type_id = 14) as total_paid',
    '(select (select coalesce(sum(cost),0) from workflow where order_uid = i.uid) + (select coalesce(sum(cost),0) from partsflow where order_uid = i.uid) + (select coalesce(sum(cost),0) from moneyflow where flow = -1 and type_id != 13 and order_uid = i.uid)) as order_total'
])
->from('orders i')
->leftJoin('customer_cars cc','i.car_id = cc.id')
->leftJoin('car_makes mk','cc.make_id = mk.id')
->leftJoin('car_models md','cc.model_id = md.id')
->leftJoin('customers c','cc.customer_id = c.id')
->where(['i.status' => 2])
->andFilterCompare('(select coalesce(sum(cost),0) from moneyflow where order_uid = i.uid and type_id = 14)','< order_total')
->all();
```

as a result i want to see all orders with status = 2 and where total_paid is less than order_total
the problem is when i add "order_total" to "addFilterCompare" i don't get any result.
Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

ended up with this solution

```
$total_paid = (new Query())->select(['coalesce(sum(cost),0)'])->from('moneyflow')->where('order_uid = i.uid')->andWhere(['=','type_id',14]);
$total_expenses = (new Query())->select(['(select (select coalesce(sum(cost),0) from workflow where order_uid = i.uid) + (select coalesce(sum(cost),0) from partsflow where order_uid = i.uid) + (select coalesce(sum(cost),0) from moneyflow where flow = -1 and type_id != 13 and order_uid = i.uid)) as total_expenses']);
$Query = (new Query())
->select([
    'i.id as order_id',
    'i.uid as order_uid',
    'i.status as order_status',
    'i.created as order_created',
    'i.car_id as car_id',
    'i.user_id as user_id',
    'cc.customer_id as customer_id',
    'cc.make_id as make_id',
    'cc.model_id as model_id',
    'cc.color_id as color_id',
    'cc.plate_country as plate_country',
    'cc.plate_text as plate_text',
    'mk.title as make_title',
    'md.title as model_title',
    'c.title as customer_title',
    'total_paid' => $total_paid,
    'total_expenses' => $total_expenses,
])
->from('orders i')
->leftJoin('customer_cars cc','i.car_id = cc.id')
->leftJoin('car_makes mk','cc.make_id = mk.id')
->leftJoin('car_models md','cc.model_id = md.id')
->leftJoin('customers c','cc.customer_id = c.id')
->where(['i.status' => 2])
->andFilterCompare($total_paid,$total_expenses,'<');
```

Comment: I would suggest using `andWhere(['<', $total_paid, $total_expenses])` instead of `andFilterCompare()` method. The `*Filter*()` methods and especially `andFilterCompare()` method are designed for different purpose and using them when working with sub-queries only adds unnecessary overhead. The `andFilterCompare()` method tries to parse its second parametr to check if the value starts with recognised operator, for example '<'. Then it tries to build condition based on the operator it finds or the default operator given in third parameter if the value doesn't start with operator.

Comment: Even better might be using `andHaving(new \yii\db\Expression('total_paid < total_expenses'))`. You can use calculated columns in `HAVING` clause so you can avoid including same sub-query twice in your query.

Comment: @MichalHynčica thank you for pointing me on "HAVING" clause. Cheers